populate javascript object by another one
I have a javascript object like this
const allData = {
  "aaa": {
    "xxx": {},
    "details": {
      "111": {
        "a": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "bbb": {
    "yyy": {},
    "details": {
      "222": {
        "a": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "ccc": {
    "zzz": {},
    "details": {
      "333": {
        "a": 100
      }
    }
  },
  "ddd": {
    "kkk": {},
    "details": {
      "444": {
        "a": 1000
      }
    }
  }
};

and I like to get all details to another one, so:
allDetails={};
$.each(allData, function (nameCont, valCont){
  console.dir(valCont.details);
  Object.defineProperty(allDetails, nameCont, valCont.details);
});
console.dir(allDetails);

I expect the result should be:
{
  "aaa": {
    "111": {
      "a": 1
    }
  },
  "bbb": {
    "222": {
      "a": 10
    }
  },
  "ccc": {
    "333": {
      "a": 100
    }
  },
  "ddd": {
    "444": {
      "a": 1000
    }
  }
}

But it doesn't work... What's wrong?
Here the fiddle

looks like jquery. if so where are the library cdn links

@cmgchess you mean in the fiddle?  It's in the javascript box: JavaScript + jQuery Slim 3.2.1 - OP is only using jquery for $.each so is not relevant to the question.,

btw idk why you using Object.defineProperty here but anyway Object.defineProperty(allDetails, nameCont, {value:valCont.details})

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Parameters
obj : The object on which to define the property.
prop : A string or Symbol specifying the key of the property to be defined or modified.
descriptor: The descriptor for the property being defined or modified.

Your call to this:
Object.defineProperty(allDetails, nameCont, valCont.details);

passes a value as the descriptor, not a descriptor, so should be:
Object.defineProperty(allDetails, nameCont, { value: valCont.details });

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/th1ves6q/


allData={
  "aaa":{
    "xxx":{},
    "details":{
      "111":{
        "a":1
      }
    }
  },
  "bbb":{
    "yyy":{},
    "details":{
      "222":{
        "a":10
      }
    }
  },
  "ccc":{
    "zzz":{},
    "details":{
      "333":{
        "a":100
      }
    }
  },
  "ddd":{
    "kkk":{},
    "details":{
      "444":{
        "a":1000
      }
    }
  }
};
allDetails={};
$.each(allData, function (nameCont, valCont){
  //console.dir(valCont.details);
  Object.defineProperty(allDetails, nameCont, { value: valCont.details });
});

console.dir(allDetails);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

View result in browser console




Nested for of using Object.entries on first loop get the first key and record its value to results creating an empty object, then on second loop get the value.details key/value and record that to results.


const allData = {
  "aaa": {
    "xxx": {},
    "details": {
      "111": {
        "a": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "bbb": {
    "yyy": {},
    "details": {
      "222": {
        "a": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "ccc": {
    "zzz": {},
    "details": {
      "333": {
        "a": 100
      }
    }
  },
  "ddd": {
    "kkk": {},
    "details": {
      "444": {
        "a": 1000
      }
    }
  }
};

const allDetails = (obj) => {
  let result = {}
  for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    result[k] = {}
    for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(v.details)) {
      result[k][key] = val
    }
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(allDetails(allData));






const allData = {
  "aaa": {"xxx": {}, "details": { "111": { "a": 1 }}},
  "bbb": {"yyy": {}, "details": { "222": { "a": 10 }}},
  "ccc": {"zzz": {}, "details": { "333": { "a": 100 }}},
  "ddd": {"kkk": {}, "details": { "444": { "a": 1000 }}}
};

const result = Object.entries(structuredClone(allData)).reduce((acc, [k,v]) => {
  acc[k] = v.details;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
// {"aaa":{"111":{"a":1}}, "bbb":{"222":{"a":10}}, "ccc":{"333":{"a":100}}, "ddd":{"444":{"a":1000}}};




https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce


use ...spread syntax
const allDetails = {...allData}


Have you read the title and the expected result data?

actually read as text, OP said 'to get ALL details to another one', if the objective is to exclude empty keys then it should be specified too. (and expected result is posted as unformatted code, hard to see difference)

Read the question, specifically: "I expect the result should be:"

"All details" is not the same as "All details".  There's a property called "details" that OP is trying move to a different position in the object hierarchy.

PS: the ... spread syntax creates a shallow clone, which potentially can irreversibly mutate the original deeply nested objects data.

hmmm, yes, my bad
